# 'Could not find your craft/ folder' error despite following installation instructions

Tags: install

Thanks in advance for any help - I'm starting to feel like a fool for coming up against errors so often. But here goes.

I have confirmed with my hosting provider that Craft CMS is compatible.

I have put /craft/ folder and the **contents** of the /public/ folder next to each other in the htdocs directory on my hosting server.

I've updated the location of the /craft/ folder in index.php (to `$craftPath = './craft';`)

When I navigate to mysite.com/admin I get `Could not find your craft/ folder. Please ensure that $craftPath is set correctly in /var/www/virtual/mysite/htdocs/index.php`

I've checked that the root folder is performing correctly - I can successfuly navigate to an image at `mysite.com/pic.jpg`.

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar set up for one particular installation and have the `$craftPath` set as follows:

```
$craftPath = 'craft';
```

Which works fine.

Comment: Thanks Stephen, but that still doesn't work unfortunately: `Could not find your craft/ folder. Please ensure that $craftPath is set correctly in /var/www/virtual/mysite.com/htdocs/index.php`

Comment: Hmm, well the only function run by `index.php` to see if the craft folder exists is `is_file` on `craft/app/index.php`. Reading up on that on PHP's documentation, it says that the function can return `false` if the `+x` permission is not set for that file for the user running PHP, so maybe worth checking the `craft`, `craft/app` and `craft/app/index.php` permissions?

Comment: @Chris In addition to permissions, another thing to check is if you have any [open_basedir](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir) restrictions in place in your php.ini file.

Comment: Thanks again Stephen - I've just checked and the permissions are set to 744 for all of those files. Although there isn't a craft/app/index.php - index.php is in the htdocs folder?

Comment: Hi @BradBell, thanks for the suggestion - I don't know what a php.ini file is unfortunately. I'll have a read around and see if I can find out.

Comment: @Chris it sounds like some of the contents of your `craft` folder are missing then, I'd try renaming the existing `craft` folder to keep a backup and then uploading the folder again directly to that location. Maybe worth taking a fresh copy from http://www.craftcms.com/ too before uploading.

Comment: Thanks Stephen - I went for a full reset in the end. Removed everything, re-downloaded from Craft site, re-uploaded as per their installation instructions, and now it's working :)

Comment: No problem, @Chris, glad you got it sorted.